# Field 'Hash' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql

Quando eu tento inserir em uma tabela aparece esse erro `Field 'Hash' doesn't have a default value`

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET SQL_MODE = ''; INSERT INTO ".SQL_TABELA."(`Chave`, `Nome`, `Categoria`, `Tamanho`, `Link`, `Hash`, `Tipo`, `Parceiro`) VALUES ('".$chave."', '".$name."', '".$category."', '".$size."', '".$link."', '".$hash."', '".$type."', '".$parceiro."')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Obs: já tentei retirado o `SET SQL_MODE = '';`

Comment: Já experimentou criar um valor padrão para o `Hash`? Por exemplo `ALTER TABLE Tabela MODIFY COLUMN Hash VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;`.

Comment: Resolveu, coloca isso como resposta por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa definir uma valor padrão para a coluna de `Hash`, por exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE Tabela MODIFY COLUMN Hash VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Se usa `NOT NULL` use `''` ao invés de `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE Tabela MODIFY COLUMN Hash VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Isto irá definir um valor padrão para a coluna, quando nenhum valor for especificado ele será utilizado. Note de ajustar o `VARCHAR(255)` para sua necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o comando

```
set @@global.sql_mode='';
```

Desta forma ira desativar o strict mode.

também pode mudar através do my.ini. procure por **sql-mode** e apague o que estiver entre aspas **""**

Caso mude no my.ini será necessário reiniciar seu mysql